# I Dropped My Phone In My Windshield Vent

Tags: dodge, windshield, dakota, defroster

So I was driving and trying to use the gps on my phone at the same time, so I thought "Maybe if I sit it here, I can see the directions and the road." I then proceeded to DROP my phone into the vent that defrosts the windshield. I have a 2004 Dodge Dakota. I can still see it, just past the grilles, but I cannot reach it. How do I go about getting it out? Do I have to take apart the whole dash, or is there a way to just take off the vent so I can reach it?

Comment: Bless you! I hope you can manage to get it out without too much trouble!

Answer (score 1):

Lolly stick with sticky tape...

but look at the grille - there may be plugs or the edge shape may indicate it is held down by hidden clips.

Make one stick with the tape securely connected with a long tongue. Use a second stick to push the tape onto the phone.

Then it is down to dexterity and being able to visualise the situation - working « blind » is a common situation. Remember those buzzer games with the bent wire?

Comment: I don't have a lolly stick but I have a butter knife and some double sided sticky tape, so we will see if this gets us anywhere. Wish me luck

Comment: This is not working. I need a way to take the entire top off so I can reach in and grab it with my hand, the vents keep getting in the way.

Comment: Duct tape has a good sticky adhesive. Wrap some of it around the end of a paint stir stick. Better yet, use 2 sticks (sticky sticks) to wiggle and grab it.